# Multiplexing in seven segment display

Tags: assembly, multiplexing, seven-segment-display

We were asked a question on multiplexing. Why is multiplexing important in utilizing the seven-segment display and which part of the code it performs the multiplexing?

```
ORG 0000H
START:
    SETB P3.3
    SETB P3.4
    MOV P1, #10100100B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.3
    MOV P1, #10110000B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.4
    SETB P3.3
    MOV P1, #10011001B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.3
    MOV P1, #10010010B
    CALL DELAY
    SETB P3.3
    SETB P3.4
    MOV P1, #10000010B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.3
    MOV P1, #11111000B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.4
    SETB P3.3
    MOV P1, #10000000B
    CALL DELAY
    CLR P3.3
    MOV P1, #10011000B
    CALL DELAY
    JMP START
DELAY: MOV R0, #45H
    DJNZ R0, $
    RET
END
```

Comment: What architecture is this asm for?  PIC or something?  Please tag it.

Comment: Code suggests there are two segments, with there common connected to P3.3 and P3.4. Is it so?